# OpenBSD 5.9 in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, openbsd

Can we confirm that bidirectional copy paste won't work between Virtual box and host os? I have installed OpenBSD 5.9 in VirtualBox where it runs fine and I want to enable copy paste between guest and host os but it won't work. OpenBSD has its own way of copypasting, seems like it can't be done even if I make a shared folder which usually enables the gues os to copy and paste files and cache between the systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OpenBSD
>
> Requires hardware virtualization to be enabled. Versions 3.7 and
>   later are supported. **Guest Additions are not available yet**.

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#guestossupport

> Shared clipboard
>
> With the Guest Additions installed, the clipboard of the guest operating system can optionally be shared

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

So, there is no shared clipboard support (unless someone gets around to writing and maintaining a guest addition).